# My Blade template content displayed twice

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I'm newbie in laravel. When I try to make master layout example, I get the content of my view printed out twice.

master.blade.php:

```
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>@yield('title')</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        @section('sidebar')
            This is the master sidebar.
        @show

        <div class="container">
            @yield('content')
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

page.blade.php:

```
@extends('layouts.master')

@section('title', 'Page Title')

@section('sidebar')


    <p>This is appended to the master sidebar.</p>
@endsection

@section('content')
    <p>This is my body content.</p>
@endsection
```

and my Route web.php:

```
Route::get('blade', function () {
    return view('page');
});
```

I trying use @stop intead of @endsection but it doesn't work.

Comment: First, the name of file should be master.blade.php (you have written master.blade.html). And second, show the content of both the files, master and page.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot showing page file.

Comment: thanks, I fixed this.

Comment: Oh, that's good...

Comment: page.blade.php and master.blade.php are the same, is  this correct?